# Programmatically force to use Google DNS for my site

Tags: dns, ip, local, resolve

How can I make so when a user goes to my website, they should not use their local ISP DNS to resolve my website IP, rather they should use Google DNS i.e 8.8.8.8

How can I configure this on my web server?

Comment: It is not possible for a website to control which DNS a client computer uses to resolve IPs. If it is a new website you simply must wait a while until all IPSs refresh their cache

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I misunderstand but how would someone get to your site in the first place without using their current DNS? You can't change someones DNS they can only change it themselves.

Comment: http://www.faizanzahid.me
This is my site but it is not accessible from within my university. However i guess it is accessible from outside (internet). What could be the problem with my uni DNS servers?